# Refreshing Azure Active Directory access token in ASP.NET Core with dependency injection for SQL Database

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I have an ASP.NET Core website (with Razor pages) that is using an Azure SQL Database with Entity Framework Core. I create the database context in the Startup.cs for dependency injection. The tricky part is that I'm using Azure Active Directory authentication against the database with Managed Identity from my App Service. So my connection string does not have any credentials in it and looks like this:

```
"DatabaseConnectionString": "Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
```

In the Startup.cs I'm getting an access token using the managed identity:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other stuff...

    var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(Configuration["DatabaseConnectionString"])
    {
        AccessToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result
    };
    services.AddDbContext<AlpinehutsDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(dbConnection));
}
```

This all works like a charm. However, after some time (I'm not sure how long exactly) the token seems to expire and then I get the following error and the database connection does no longer work until I restart the entire app service:

```
2019-07-30 08:31:25.635 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvoker: Executing handler method AlpinHutsDashboard.Pages.HutsModel.OnGetAsync - ModelState is Valid
2019-07-30 08:31:25.635 +00:00 [Information] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure: Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'AlpinehutsDbContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
2019-07-30 08:31:25.861 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: An error occurred using the connection to database 'mydb' on server 'tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433'.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.WaitForPendingOpen()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnectionAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)ClientConnectionId:17e2a3f3-9dba-4c30-baff-5fa9e5e082c6Error Number:18456,State:1,Class:14ClientConnectionId before routing:7dc72f29-efa2-420d-8f28-8d63de1c059cRouting Destination:f0ae6a8cac94.tr5.westeurope1-a.worker.database.windows.net,11017
```

So my question is: How to refresh the token when I initially only get it on startup?

Comment: You could register a DB context factory class that gets a DB context from DI and creates a new connection for it (with token) before returning it. That might be inefficient though :/

Comment: would you have an example for this? How would I integrate this with my Razor Page model classes? Their constructor today just expects a DbContext

Comment: I don't have an example. Instead of requiring the DB context directly, they would require your context factory class and get the context from it. I don't have my laptop right now, you could also check if there is a function that you could override in the context that is executed while opening the connection.

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, it is caused by that you passing the `dbConnection` to `AlpinehutsDbContext`. When initiailizing `AlpinehutsDbContext`, it will always use the `dbConnection`. And then, if the connection is invalid, it will throw error.

You could try to initialize `dbConnection` when initializing `AlpinehutsDbContext` like

```
services.AddDbContext<AlpinehutsDbContext>(options =>
{
    var dbConnection = new SqlConnection(Configuration["DatabaseConnectionString"])
    {
        AccessToken = new AzureServiceTokenProvider().GetAccessTokenAsync("https://database.windows.net/").Result
    };
    options.UseSqlServer(dbConnection);
});
```

For this way, it will retrive the neweast token when initialize `AlpinehutsDbContext`.

Comment: What is the difference between  OP code and yours?